# Aside height should be 100% covering the whole side

Tags: css, height, sidebar

Check out my below examples.

// Removed due to deleted content

```
.aside {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 195px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #ebddca;
    height: 100%;
}
```

So far I haven't been able to find the correct solution. I'm getting in the right direction though. The thing is, in my above "Example #1", there is a scrollbar on the right even when there is only a few lines of code in the "main" section. I only want a scrollbar to be displayed once there is more lines of code, like in "Example #2".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you are giving   100 % height to any  element , you should also set body and html document height to 100%.The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
header,
footer,
article,
section,
hgroup,
nav,
figure {
  display: block
}
body {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  background-color: #f8f4eb;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
/*
 *  HTML5 Sections
 */

.header {
  height: 72px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 52px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.main {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f8f4eb;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.aside {
  
  float: left;
  width: 195px;
 
  background-color: #ebddca;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<aside class="aside" id="asidecontainer">

  <div class="asidewrapper">

    <font color="#000">The background of this aside bar should be totally to the bottom of the page.</font>

  </div>
</aside>
<div id="asidehider" class="asideborder"></div>

<main class="main" id="main">

  <font color="#000">
        
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
        All the content goes here<br />
    
    </font>

</main>
```

Comment: I edited my OP to post an example for this solution. I had this before and it didn't work, as you can see in example #1

Comment: what ever i have suggested above is working in example 2 posted by you , is there any other problem?

Comment: As stated: With the second example (test2), it solved my issue only for a bit. Once the aside is 100%, it cuts the whole page off. But there is more content below in the "main", which is now not getting displayed. So yeah it may seem like it is working but it is not. There is still a whole lot more that does not get displayed.

Comment: I've edited the test2. There should be 70 lines displayed, but there are only 49, it get's cut off.

Comment: so how do you want to display that content 1.scrolling whole page 2.scrolling only the main container?

Comment: Scrolling whole page. Because I can add "overflow:auto" on the main, but then there are two scrollbars. One for the whole page and one for the main. And I just want to scroll the main page and keep the aside to 100% height.

Comment: Thanks, it works if there is much content, but is there isn't enough to cover the whole page, the aside height is not 100% as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/3xxp21fn/1/

Comment: min-height:100%; add this  to .main in your CSS  it will work.

Comment: Edited my OP again because it's almost fixed but not quite yet :(

Comment: Think I fixed it using calc(100% - 124px) on the main, which is 100% minus the header and top menu. Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 3):

your `<aside>` and `<main>` has to have a parent element which is displayed as a flex and has aligned items. You also have to clean up aside and main classes in css. [jsfiddle file](https://jsfiddle.net/28xs0w7j/)

Comment: It works, but the sidebar is only as high as the main content: http://ronbrouwers.nl/test3/home1.html - And I want it to be 100% all the time.

Comment: you have to add `html, body {height:100%}` to CSS file and then height:100% to .wrapper [link](https://jsfiddle.net/28xs0w7j/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Use this class.

```
.aside {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 195px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #ebddca;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

key is to use `100vh` instead of `100%`

Comment: i'm not sure that `vh` would work for the OP. If the body content exceeds the viewport height then the sidebar will be cut off.

Answer (score 1):

Only add height:100px to the `body` and `html`.

**Problem**
You give `height:100%;` to the `aside`which is trying to get from its parents where they do not have height.

```
html,
body
{
 height:100%;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hcyzx0j7/2/)

Comment: I edited my OP to post an example for this solution. I had this before and it didn't work, as you can see in example #1