# give div 100% height of browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I combined [morphsearch](http://tympanus.net/Development/MorphingSearch/) with [google search](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/09/google-powered-site-search-ajax-jquery/search.html) and now have a custom search for my site. however, the morph search refuses to occupy 100% window height when called. My html..

```html
<div id="morphsearch" class="morphsearch">       
    <form id="searchForm" class="morphsearch-form" method="post">
        <input id="s" class="morphsearch-input" type="search" placeholder="Search Dundaah..."/>
        <input class="morphsearch-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" />         
    </form>        
    <div id="resultsDiv" class="morphsearch-content2"></div>
 <span class="morphsearch-close"></span>
    <span class="morphsearch-close2"></span>        
</div>
```

The links to the css, [component.css](http://dundaah.com/test/component.css) the js [script2.js](http://dundaah.com/test/script2.js) and [search.js](http://dundaah.com/test/search.js) an example of the problem [website](http://dundaah.com/docs/sun) (click on the red fist to see the search). I've tried 100vh, didn't work...much appreciated.

Comment: looks like 100% in my browsers (Chrome, FF, IE) - which browser are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389583/aside-height-should-be-100-covering-the-whole-side/33389633#33389633 this might help

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a couple of ways:

**CSS 1**

You set the #morphsearch position to absolute, make sure #morphsearch dosent have parents, and if he does make sure they dont have relative, absolute or fixed positions.

```
#morphsearch { position: absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
```

**CSS 2**

Set `min-height` and `height 100%` to `html` and `body`

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
$('#morphsearch').css({
    'width': $(window).width(), 'height': $(window).height()
});
```

Comment: thank you but hasn't worked out for me, when the morpsearch is open, it's still not occupying the full browser window, some content behind the overlay can still be srolled

Comment: Make a fiddle with the CSS and HTML